# Unity audio source form external sources not loading

Tags: unity-game-engine

For some reason, the audio clip wont play. I even chacked it with `Debug.log(audioSource.clip.LoadState);` and it returned

> Loaded

. I dont know what goes wrong and prevents the source from playing the clip. Also, the clip name is blank.

The code :

```
IEnumerator LoadMusic(string path, AudioSource audioSource)
{
    if (File.Exists(path))
    {
        using (UnityWebRequest uwr = UnityWebRequestMultimedia.GetAudioClip(path, AudioType.WAV))
        {
            yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();
            var uwrClip = DownloadHandlerAudioClip.GetContent(uwr);
            audioSource.clip = uwrClip;
        }
    }
}

private void LoadAssets()
{
    if (charts.Length == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    else if (startingValue != currentDropdownValue)
    {
        startingValue = currentDropdownValue;
        string musicToLoad = currentFilePath;
        StartCoroutine(LoadMusic(musicToLoad, SelectorAudioPreview));
        SelectorAudioPreview.Play();
    }
}
```

(I know that i could've used charts.Lenght != 0, but I was too tired to think straight back then.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `audioSource.Play();` after `audioSource.clip = uwrClip;`
‘
And remember to check if in your scene there is a audio listener. Check also that the audioSource settings are ok to listen, like the volume, mute, distance...

Comment: Is there a way to play the a audio clip from LoadAssets?